# How can I ask polling questions regarding the UI on SE sites without them getting closed?

Tags: discussion, policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

If I ask a polling question (on MSO) about how to improve the SE Graphical User Interface, or what aspects of the GUI are bugging users, I suppose the question would be closed as a polling question. So my question is: How should I ask such a question to avoid it gets closed?

Comment: One problem is that, by your own admission, you're asking "polling questions". The FAQ covers what kinds of questions you should ask. And a quick check of the other upvoted questions on the site should also give you a good idea.

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe, at all, but Cody's reply is good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need for such a question. UI improvement suggestions already get posted as questions here on meta under the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag, where they can be discussed and voted on as appropriate.

So such a poll would be more or less equivalent to the [requests tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests).