# To whom should we award bounties on Meta?

Tags: support, bounties, meta

I have recently started a bounty to draw more attention to [this FAQ/feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187945/make-the-faq-about-page-clear-about-the-meaning-of-downvoted-questions) (yes I know, this question is going to draw even more attention to it, I swear this is not on purpose).

It has indeed got more attention, as I got three answers, two of them being reasonably developed:

- [The one with the most upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188521/225020) disagrees with me
- [The one with the least upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188518/225020) agrees with me

Both are somewhat useful, but I *feel* the second one is more useful (slightly longer and more developed, and contains a link), trying to be as impartial as possible. Given the votes on Meta represent agreement and not usefulness, should I:

1. award the bounty to the answer most people agree with?
2. or award the bounty to the answer I think is more useful? (given this evaluation may be biased, even though I try not to)

Comment: It is your rep and your choice.

Comment: at Meta, votes frequently bandwagon, so it is especially important to resist pack mentality when making up your mind about posts. One of my bounties is [awarded to heavily downvoted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143951/give-moderators-a-tool-to-invalidate-votes-between-users#comment412595_143966 "for the reasons explained here") and I stand by it no matter how others voted

Comment: Clearly they should be awarded to [answers with funny pictures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109720/131541) also. On Fridays :-)

Comment: Yes fun fun fun fun is a valid reason for awarding bounties.

Comment: Ok, thx guys for the comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main point is **which answer is the most helpful for you (or the thread)**?

Don't necessarily go with the most voted. Go with the one *YOU* feel is the best. It's your bounty and thus you spend it for the answer that *YOU* think is the best.

Even though the evaluation would be biased... so what? It's your bounty... If you think the guy brings up good arguments for your cause, just bounty him! After all you want something to be implemented and if what he brings up help, well great! (Same thing would go for an answer against you that would make you realize that your idea should not be implemented after all or what ever similar to this).

Comment: +1 Ok, thx for the time to answer!

Answer (score 5):

I would go with no. 2 - it is your rep, your question and the answer must be satisfactory to you.

Look at it this way, it is like going to a bookstore - which of three books do you buy?  The popular one or the one that answers your questions and provides a good reference (they may be one and the same, maybe different).

Comment: +1 yep that does make sense, thx!