# Please consider displaying reputation decreases in the Achievements trophy icon

Tags: feature-request, reputation, design, achievements-dialog

**UPDATE**

Overhauling my post here and voting to reopen, since the dupe has a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined),

Recently, [a dodgy equality operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361783/in-case-of-loss-of-reputation-a-green-icon-lights-up-with-an-inscription-like#comment1207306_361783) started sending us notifications of negative reputation changes.  I thought it was [here to stay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361783/in-case-of-loss-of-reputation-a-green-icon-lights-up-with-an-inscription-like#comment1207084_361783), but Brian reported that:

> There are no plans to keep showing negative scores.

Why?  The "bug" doesn't appear to affect anything else.  Why fix the bug that's actually causing something good?  Oded (who no longer works for SE) [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219665/248072):

> We want to let you know about good things as soon as they happen - that's what our real-time notifications are for.
> Negative reputation changes are... well... negative. So we are not in a hurry to let you know about them.

Your mistake.  Posts that get downvotes should, in theory, need more attention than those lucky enough to receive upvotes (which has been said by at least four others).  So please, SE, can we reconsider that [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag (or just don't bother fixing that lucky mistake)?

---

**ORIGINAL**

Can we make it so a downvote, or other reputation decrease will highlight the Achievements trophy icon, or alert you in some other way?  A downvote might mean there is a problem with your post such as being off-topic, ethically wrong, or inappropriate, and thus would warrant a bit more attention than the extra 10 reputation an upvote gives you.  Could this also extend to a notification when you lose rep, say, because of a removed post where you had posted a well-accepted answer?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125980/notifications-on-negative-score

Answer (score 5):

As a frequent poster, I would find this useful.  It could even be an opt-in, if we didn't want to push negative feedback on people who don't want it.

I participate in multiple sites on the network, so having one central place where everything gets pushed is useful.  Downvotes on my answers alert me to potential problems that might need correcting (perhaps they're outdated, confusing, or I misunderstood the question).  Quick responses to these (especially while they're still fresh and getting attention) can enable the back-and-forth feedback required to address these issues.  I once had an answer get downvoted; I noticed it, posted a comment asking for feedback on how I could make it better, received some, and then used that feedback to turn a -1 score answer into a +1 score answer.

Having this information allows me to improve my contributions and make the network better.  We should enable this.

Comment: It's been [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362013/798831)... an opt-in sounds like the best idea, so that the people who view negative reputation changes differently don't have to see them.  Do you know of any scripts that do this?

Comment: @Ollie I don't, though others may