# Why are negative counts in the achievement dialog sometimes shown, but not always?

Tags: support, down-votes, achievements-dialog

Close voters:  [Why do reputation drops not highlight the Achievements icon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219652/178179) does not address the question "When are negative counts in the achievement dialog supposed to be shown in the top row?  They are shown sometimes, but not always."

---

Negative counts aren't shown in the achievement dialog's top row:

[image]

-

Update: sometimes, negative counts are shown in the achievement dialog's top row:

[image]

so the behavior seems inconsistent.

When are negative counts in the achievement dialog supposed to be shown in the top row?

Comment: [status-by-design]

Comment: In addition to the post @DavidPostill recommended, I wrote a request for this feature, or something similar.  Here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350358/display-reputation-decreases-in-the-achievements-trophy-icon

Comment: @Ollie thx, already partly implemented btw, see question edit.

Comment: @DavidPostill see question edit

Comment: Your net change on that site is actually 0, because you also gained 2 from accepting an answer on that site. The site is thus not shown because it has a 0 change. Does that second event not appear in the list for the day? As far as I know, it should. I just tested accepting an answer on an old question and it showed up for me...

Comment: @animuson whoops, thanks, you're right! I had forgotten. Then I'd suggest showing a `0` on the top row, to still reflect the activity, to be consistent  to what is done in the reputation tab on a user's profile. No strong preference though.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, you should post that as a new FR

Comment: @Luuklag good point, done: [Add 0 in the achievement dialog's top row if a Stack Exchange website has some rep activities that sum up to 0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350688/178179)