# Add 0 in the achievement dialog's top row if a Stack Exchange website has some rep activities that sum up to 0

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog

Add 0 in the achievement dialog's top row if a Stack Exchange website has some rep activities that sum up to 0.

[image]

I think that'd be more consistent to what is done in the reputation tab on a user's profile when a question has some rep activities that sum up to 0.