# Closed post message, "Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege" is misleading

Tags: support, closed-questions, post-notices

The closed post message, "Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes privilege" to see who voted to close a question is misleading, as the list and message are only viewable if you have 3000 reputation and are *not* the post owner.  This screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of post notice given to post owner]

is of [one of my closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350358/display-reputation-decreases-in-the-achievements-trophy-icon), and I am not seeing the message or list, but I can see the list and message on all closed questions that aren't mine.  If this is because the close voters shouldn't be shown to the OP in an easy way to prevent potential bad actions, then shouldn't the wording of the message be changed?

Comment: The "Viewable by" message refers to the text directly to the right of the eye icon, not to the list of close voters. Essentially, the "extra advice" corresponding to the close message is only shown to the post authors and those with close/reopen privileges. E.g. if you opened that question incognito, you'd only see the top portion appended with "Closed 2 months ago" and nothing else. I agree it is confusing when the text and the description of the text are separated by another line that is not ever hidden in any circumstance. I don't see why that can't remain a part of the top section always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: It conveys the fact that the information is still viewable (in the post's timeline), even if not in the post notice**. Rewording it might imply that they don't have access.

[kristinalustig](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/344828/kristinalustig) has a great explanation of the logic behind the language [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/165261):

> We discussed changing the post notice language for users who do have permissions but decided to leave it as-is, so that still indicates that both the post owner and those with close/reopen vote privileges can see the names. Because post owners are still able to see who voted to close/reopen their question by going into the post history, it would be inaccurate to say that they do not have access to that information. It's merely harder to reach (and lower rep users are much less likely to find it).