# In case of loss of reputation, a green icon lights up with an inscription like -n

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, mobile-web, top-bar

Recently, the top-bar has changed a little and after that, if you lose your reputation, the green icon will light up there:

[image: the inbox icon on the left and a "-1" with a green background on the right]

It would be nice if instead of green showing, the background was either red or nothing at all when a user loses reputation.

Comment: Putting a link to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361792/is-it-intentional-that-the-green-rep-change-bubble-no-longer-has-a-plus-sign) here as well, for whoever finds it. Those two seem related.

Comment: At least they're finally showing negative rep changes! ;)

Comment: Why isn't it red to match the stock market `:)`

Comment: Would be surprising if [this was an intended change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/241919).

Comment: I caused this with a bad equality operator.  A fix is incoming but there are no plans to keep showing negative scores here.

Comment: @BrianNickel Bugger.  I don't suppose the bad equality operator can hang around for a bit?

Comment: @BrianNickel the bug has been fixed at the moment, so could you please put [status-completed]?

Comment: @rene for the first time, someone started a contest when I asked my question! thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and the mobile topbar once again hides non-positive rep changes like the desktop version.

Now I won't be able to see all the rep I lose for unshipping this rogue feature.

Comment: And I won't see the one I lost for downvoting this.  That is kind of disappointing, Brian.  Is there an official reason why SE won't implement this, *aside* from former employee Oded's reasoning?

Comment: My reasoning here is purely consistency.  The mobile views are already an under-maintained and unloved feature from the development side of things, and giving it quirks only makes the situation worse.  That said, we have a product organization now that is definitely willing to revisit decisions developers made almost a decade ago, so it wouldn't hurt to restart that discussion.

Comment: I was thinking more in that this should be a new meta discussion, e.g. "It's 2021, does this should we include negative scores in the topbar."  That's the best way for community requests get into our backlog.

Comment: I could write a new one... or should I edit [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350358/please-consider-displaying-reputation-decreases-in-the-achievements-trophy-icon) one, to avoid dupe-votes?

Comment: Oh, in that case I'll just bring that post to the team's attention.

Comment: Why did @BrianNickel lose rep? The bounty message says that the bounty is to compensate loss of rep.

Comment: I haven't lost any rep (or at least the total change was positive).  I think my tongue-in-cheek answer elicited the bounty.