# Is it intentional that the green rep change bubble no longer has a plus sign?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

(Note: While this image is taken from a desktop browser in F12 mode, it's in line with what I see on my phone and my tablet)

[image]

The text in the green bubble on top-right used to be like `+10`, and it still is `+10` on desktop site.

Is this a <s>bug</s> feature or a recent design change?

Comment: Might be related to the same change that now causes [reputation loss to show there too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361783/369802)?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Makes a lot of sense. Judging by time they must be the same change/release.

Comment: This is a bug.  I was cleaning up some duplicate code and chopped this off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed.

The plus is back.